# Why does taking the residue commute with the discriminant if $B$ is free over $A$ and not in general?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $A$ its ring of integers, $L/K$ be a finite extension, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

**Lemma (residue of the discriminant):** Assume $B$ is free over $A$, let $a$ be an ideal in $A$ and let the overline $\overline{e_i}$ denote the image of the residue map $A \rightarrow A/a$ or $B \rightarrow B/aB$. Then $\overline{D_{B/A}} = D_{\overline{B}/\overline{A}}$.

> *proof*: Consider any basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ of $B/A$. Then $(\overline{e_1},...,\overline{e_n})$ is a basis for $\overline{B}/\overline{A}$ and we can calculate the discriminants from these basis. They obviously coincide.

My question is: why can one not prove a similar lemma for $B$ not necessarily free over $A$? I'd like it to sound something like:

**fake lemma:** Let $D$ be the ideal in $A$ generated by the Gramian of all basis $(x_1,...,x_n)$ of $L/K$ which sit in $B$ (i.e. are integral), that is let $D$ be the relative discriminant $B/A$. Then $\overline {D}$ coincides with the ideal generated by the Gramian of all $(\overline{x_1},...,\overline{x_n})$.

---

**Addendum:** To answer the Alex Youcis' question of why I think this is not true, here is the set up. We proved the following theorem in class, which used several lemmas including the residue of the discriminant lemma above. If my fake lemma were true, however, we'd get the theorem much more easily. Let me state the theorem, the lemmas used (without proof), and the reasoning to connect all of them while avoiding my fake lemma.

**Theorem:** a prime ideal $p$ ramifies in $B$ iff $p|D_{B/A}$ (in other words, the relative discriminant of $B$ over $A$ sits in $p$).

The proof uses several lemmas which I'm only going to state.

**Lemma 1:** $p$ ramifies in $B$ iff $D_{B/pB/A/pA} = 0$.

**Lemma 2:** Let $A'$, $B'$ denote the localization with respect to the multiplicative system $A \setminus p$. Then $B'/p'B' = B/pB$ and  $A'/p'A' = A/pA$.

**Lemma 3:** If $a$ is an ideal $A$, then $D_{B/aB/A/aA} = 0$ iff $p$ ramifies in $B$

By lemma 2 $D_{B/pB/A/pA} = D_{B'/p'B'/A'/p'A'}$, and this is equal to $0$ iff, by residue of the discriminant lemma, $D_{B'/A'} \in p$. On the other hand, any element in the generating set of $D_{B/A}$ is the Gramian of some basis of $L/K$, which sits in $B$, hence of the form $D_{B/A}(x_1,...,x_n) = \det^2 (a'_{ij})D_{B'/A'}$, for some change of basis matrix $(a'_{ij})$. On the left hand side we have an element in $A$, on the right, by assumption, an element in $p'$. Hence $p$ ramifies in $B$ iff $D_{B/A} \subset A \cap p' = p$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $\overline{a}$. You mean $B/aB$? Why do you think this is not true? It seems to me that as long as you define the discriminant corectly, it works. .

Comment: @AlexYoucis Take a look again. I hope I added more motivation now.